# Programmatically Controlled gimbal

Tags: camera

I am looking for a pretty specific product. A programmatically controlled gimbal for a camera. I want to be able to change the pan/tilt/roll of the camera by sending instructions through a cable, not through bluetooth or wireless. Does such a product exist? I have received recommendations for companies like DJI and Gremsy but their equipment is all controlled through bluetooth/wireless. Any recommendation?

Comment: Raspberry pi + some motors?

Comment: I was looking for a consumer/off the shelf solution.

Comment: That is a consumer solution, but more for the tweakers community indeed....

Comment: The reason gimbal controllers, the same as focus-pulling controllers & remote displays are all wireless is that the camera may not be in reach of a wire half the time it's in use - meaning two entire control systems would be needed. No-one is going to buy a wired only system, so no-one is going to make one any more. No steadicam/ronin op wants to be tripping over cables. Even on a crane, where wiring would still work, the systems in place are already wireless. Only the crane itself, as a self-contained unit, is wired [unless it's programmable, in which case the remote will also be wireless]